# Django haystack doesn't add to Solr index. [Works with whoosh, fails with Solr]

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, whoosh

During development I used whoosh as a backend, and now want to switch to
solr. I installed solr, changed the settings, to
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE, and HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL.

Now when I try to update or rebuild the index it fails with
`Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: None]`
 .

All searches are also wrong with  0 results returned for all queries..
This work if I change to whoosh. However, I have a RealTimeSearch
index set, and during model creation I am getting no warning about not
being able to write to search index. (From which I am assuming that data is being correctly being written to solr index.

I can see that solr is running by going directly to the port where solr started.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error usually happens when your schema.xml file is improperly configured.

You can use `python manage.py build_solr_schema > schema.xml` to generate the schema.

In order to actually have solr use it, you typically place it in `example/solr/conf/schema.xml`

Finally: watch the log output of your Solr server. During development I have it running via `java -jar start.jar` and it implicitly prints to my screen. Otherwise, your logs go into the `example/logs` directory.

---

Additionally, double check the `HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL`. It should not have a trailing slash.

Comment: This is happening after I have copied the schema.xml over to example/solr/conf/schema.xml. The result I get on `rebuild_index` is http://dpaste.de/vOkU/

Comment: Also looks like if it is not even hitting Solr as the console started has no new logs

Comment: Yes, the 404 not found suggests the url is wrong.

Double check your HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL perhaps? Mine looks like: http://localhost:8983/solr

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Had set the url to localhost:8983

Answer (score 4):

I was having this error. The first reason was that I hadn't rebuilt the schema.xml, but there is something more... After you rebuild the schema.xml you must to restart Solr. Doing this, Solr will recognize the schema changes and will know the new fields.

Comment: @astrocybernaute it depends. if you are running it on tomcat you can restart tomcat itself doing `sudo service tomcat7 restart` or in case you are using the tomcat manager, you can login (http://<YOUR_SERVER_DOMAIN_OR_IP>:8000/manager/html) and restart it there. 

If you are just running solr using `java -jar start.jar` or something like that, I recommend you to shutdown the executions (CRTL-c) and start it again.